# Auto Backup / Instant Upload of other folders

Tags: google-plus, instant-upload

Is there a way, natively or through 3rd party app that I can define folders to watch on my phone that auto backsup photos to a particular album or to the autobackup section of my Google+ account.

I dont want to use other services such as dropbox etc, I want to know if theres an option to keep it all with Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Google+ 4.3 you can [select which local folder](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1647509#folderab) are included in auto backup.

Comment: If you're happy to use Google Drive, there is an Android app called DriveSync by ttxapps that will do what you want. I use the Dropbox version called DropSync and it works brilliantly.

Comment: @Nucleotide you should probably comment on the question and not my answer.

Comment: Oops! I'm using the new Android app. Still getting used to it. :)

Comment: Selecting folders is now available.